# Using MATLAB, is there a way to get a 2D visualisation of data points that are in 6D space?

Tags: matlab

Part of an assignment of mine is to provide a 2D visualisation (plots) of some of my data points that are stored in a matrix. I'm slightly confused because the data is actually in 6D space (i.e. each row has 6 columns like `0 1 0 8 8 2`).

Is there something I'm missing or does this genuinely not make sense? Is this something MATLAB can do?

Edit: Is something like this possible?

[image: Is something like this possible?]

Comment: if each row has 6 columns, does it make your matrix a 2D matrix of 6 x n element?

Comment: It makes my matrix a 2D matrix of n x 6 (n = number of rows)

Answer (score 3):

Though I wouldn't consider it visualizing 6D data, you can get the linked plot with a simple call to [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html):

```
A = rand(6);
x = 1:6;

plot(x,A'); % Transpose A to plot rows since it's square, see plot documentation
```

Which produces the following:

[image: yay]

From the documentation:

> If one of X or Y is a vector and the other is a matrix, then the
>   matrix must have dimensions such that one of its dimensions equals the
>   vector length. If the number of matrix rows equals the vector length,
>   then the plot function plots each matrix column versus the vector. If
>   the number of matrix columns equals the vector length, then the
>   function plots each matrix row versus the vector. If the matrix is
>   square, then the function plots each column versus the vector.

Comment: Hey I'm actually working on something similar and this answer was useful. I'm curious to know what the x and y axes represent in this case?

Comment: @eyesenberg as the documentation states, `x` is along the x-axis and each column of `A` (because A is square, I transposed it so it's plotting the original rows) is plotted vs `x` on the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
surf(2Dmatrix)
```

You can read more here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

If your matrix is 2D image, simply use

```
figure; imshow(2Dmatrix, [])
```

If you leave the square bracket empty, the limit will be automatic. When the figure is displayed you can change it to different colormap by `Edit > Colormap`.

Comment: Hi Nhan. Thanks for your help. I can see what imshow(...) does but it doesn't look nice. Can you look at my edit? Do you know how I can get graphs like that?